# How can I make taro crust scallops without deep frying?

Tags: scallops

I want mimic this Chiu Chow restaurant in Hong Kong's deep-fried scallops coated with mashed taro crust.

To protect health and prevent oil splattering, I don't want deep fry. Can I bake or pan fry?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a recipe for this that you are trying to modify, or are you asking us for the entire recipe?

Comment: If the taro takes longer to cook in the oven than in they fryer, then you end up with either under-cooked taro or over-cooked scallops (possibly both).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe, try it out and report back.

The texture of the crust will not be the same (it is never the same when baking vs. frying).

It will be more dense as the water in the taro will not evaporate as quickly, which is what give the light texture that the picture show.